# Generate IDP Certificate in Azure AD for SSO

Tags: java, azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am implementing SSO with Azure AD for three applications.I can able to make it work for the two applications which is developed in .Net but the third application is running on Java and need to enable SSO for that.In the configuring page of the Java application it requires an IDP Certificate and I am not sure where to get that from the portal.Could someone show me some pointer around this?

I have searched through web and most of the posts talk about we need to upload X.509 certificate.But I cant see the process to obtain one.

Comment: are you talking about Azure AD Access control Service ? Because it still a different beast. And do you refer to this guide: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-java-authenticate-users-access-control-eclipse/

Comment: I have already gone through the link, but still not clear about the creation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to obtain the X.509 certificate for the application.

In the azure portal under Active Directory on Application Tabs will be having the list of application like developing and owns.Click on the Application you want to create certificate for.on the bottom banner there will be link saying view endpoints.In that pop up first link will be federation link load that in browser search for x509.copy the string save it as .crt and you are done.

here is the [link](https://letslearnazure.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/create-x-509-certificate-for-azure-ad-to-enable-sso/)

Comment: Just to be clear for any future person who stumbles upon this, it's just the string inside of the <X509Certificate> node